# Web : What is the best way to build the back-end/front-end relation?

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, angular, jwt

I'm starting a PHP/JS Web project using Laravel for the back end and Angular 2 for the front end.
But I'm wondering how I should relate these two frameworks.

The two solutions I found was :

1 - Writing the whole Angular project in laravel's public folder and launch it from a app.blade.php in a Laravel view. Which makes it easy to pass the Laravel Auth data to Angular, but makes the public folder quite huge and probably too messy.

2 - Having two separate projects. And call the Laravel's api routes using JWT (I don't know a lot about that but read that it was a nice option).

So my question is, which of these 2 solutions is the best and why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm gonna give you a third option, which is the one I use for my projects with Laravel + AngularJS

So I use Laravel for 2 things:
*Retriving views
*Managing an API

For example if you request something like project.com/users Laravel will manage this and return the users.blade.php view

Then in this view I use angular to ask for data to the API (In laravel) and retrive it and load it on the HTML.

With this I take advantage of Sessions with Laravel (By retriving the views) and I take advantage of AngularJS with controllers and data-binding.

Also the directory structure is ordered because all views are in resources/views and for the controllers of angular I put them on public/js/controllers.

Hope this help you